# Error : Could not find or load main class com.xamarin.androidx.jetifierWrapper.Main

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After updating the visual studio to the latest version i'm facing the below mentioned error.
Could not find or load main class com.xamarin.androidx.jetifierWrapper.Main xx.xx.Droid

tried below mentioned points without any luck:

Deleted all package folder and restored

Updated the package to latest available version (XF to 5.0)

Uninstalled visual studio and re-installed

Re installed the Android SDK

Deleted Bin-Obj, clean and rebuild multiple times

Using the below mentioned Visual studio and package version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.8+32002.261
Microsoft .NET
Framework Version 4.8.04084
Xamarin 16.11.000.197
(d16-11@6934992)
Xamarin.Android SDK 12.0.0.3 (d16-11/f0e3c2d)

Package:
xamarin.android.support.xx version : 28.0.0.3   targetFramework="monoandroid10.0"
Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration version : 1.0.8

Please let me know if anyone have any suggestion/solution.
Thanks

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this issue happens while building the project itself not during deployment

Comment: Did you still run this app well? Have you try to update other package to the latest version?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT  We found that this issue because of inside Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration package folder jetifierWrapper file was held by system antivirus after removing from antivirus now this error not showing up. Now showing other error: 
Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipException: Unexpected libzip error: EOF

Comment: It is likely that the antivirus caused the new problem also. Disable the antivirus, and re-install everything, until you get it working. Then re-enable antivirus.